# Add custom property to android View using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view

I know it's possible to create custom properties with Kotlin by creating my own class, but is it possible to assign a custom property to an android `View` without extending the `View` class?

I'm trying to create an `order` property which will be either 1, 2 or 3:

```
fun View.setOrder(order: Int){
    // not sure what to put here
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to create an order property which will be either 1, 2 or 3

Your syntax is for an extension function, not an extension property.

If you want an extension `var`, use:

```
var View.order: Int
  get() = getTag(R.id.tag_order) as Int
  set(value: Int) = setTag(R.id.tag_order, value)
```

where you define an `id` resource named `tag_order`. We need view tags to be unique for the entire app, and various libraries use tags, so an `id` resource gives you a value that should not collide with those from anyone else. So, you would have a `res/values/ids.xml` (or whatever) file with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <id name="tag_order" />
</resources>
```

If the value will be 1, 2, or 3, though, probably you should use an `enum class` rather than an `Int`.